# Get a single value out of any statistics tests (e.g. value of spearman rho out of cor.test)

Tags: r

Statistics test in R outputs many descriptions. While they are useful, how can we just output or extract single values?

```
> cor.test(x,y,method="spearman", exact=F)

        Spearman's rank correlation rho

data:  x and y 
S = 12767993, p-value = 0.0001517
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0 
sample estimates:
      rho 
-0.188074
```

particularly, what to do to just get out these values **0.0001517** and **-0.188074** so I can store them for further analyses?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use `$` subsetting of the test object. The relevant names are `p.value` and `estimate`.

```
> tst<-cor.test(1:10,rnorm(10),method="spearman")
> tst

        Spearman's rank correlation rho

data:  1:10 and rnorm(10) 
S = 140, p-value = 0.6818
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0 
sample estimates:
      rho 
0.1515152
```

.

```
> tst$p.value
[1] 0.6818076
> tst$estimate
      rho 
0.1515152
```

**Edit**

The other answers point out that you can investigate the structure of the object with `str` to find the names to use with `$` subsetting. You can also find out the names with `names`:

```
> names(tst)
[1] "statistic"   "parameter"   "p.value"     "estimate"    "null.value" 
[6] "alternative" "method"      "data.name"
```

Another thing to consider is that you are looking at the printed version of the object, and the print method may be performing some calculations (it isn't in this case). You can check the object class with `class(tst)` which reveals it is of class `htest`. `print.htest` is the relevant print method, but this is non-visible, so use `getAnywhere(print.htest)` to view it.

Comment: While it's been already dealt with in other answers, I think you could also point out that `str()` will show variables that can be called using a `$` sign. There's also a trick - you sometimes see values only in `summary` and `print` (they are calculated based on data from the object), but not in the object itself. Then, you have to subset, for example, the `summary(object)$variable`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick **reply**, but there's still a problem with the _estimate_ value. I just want to have the numerical output **0.1515152** of _estimate_ isolated, hence stored. Btw, just curious, is there any complete guide on how I can isolate printed output, perhaps like the one involving **getAnywhere(print.htest)**? But I think that's just one of many steps to do, isn't it? I'm totally newbie in R :(, but in Perl.

Comment: Oops, I think I miss something. I just don't know why the word **rho** is kept printed even after reassigning in different name, and I thought it affects the value; in fact it doesn't, do it? So, like my previous question, what's behind this? I think I've asked too may trivial questions.

Comment: @Rivo Suoth Its the name attribute of the object, see `?names`. The numerical output is the same as if it didn't have a name, but you can remove the names of an object `x` with `names(x) <- NULL`.

Answer (score 18):

```
test.res <- cor.test(x,y,method="spearman", exact=F)
```

Use str(test.res) to see the structure of your object

```
> str(test.res)
List of 8
 $ statistic  : Named num 182
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "S"
 $ parameter  : NULL
 $ p.value    : num 0.785
 $ estimate   : Named num -0.103
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "rho"
 $ null.value : Named num 0
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "rho"
 $ alternative: chr "two.sided"
 $ method     : chr "Spearman's rank correlation rho"
 $ data.name  : chr "1:10 and rnorm(10)"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
```

Any of these is available by using $ notation. If you are looking for getting the p.value use the following:

```
test.res$p.value
```

Answer (score 7):

```
test.res <- cor.test(x,y,method="spearman", exact=F)
test.res[1:8]
```

what you are looking for will be in there.

for specific values add another index prefix as follows:

```
test.res[1][1]
```

to find a specific element you could `str(test.res)` to find its location and subsitute in above such as `test.res[1][5]`