# Grabbing certain results out of multiple t.test outputs to create a table

Tags: r, statistics

I have run 48 t-tests (coded by hand instead of writing a loop) and would like to splice out certain results of those `t.test`s to create a table of the things I'm most interested in.

Specifically, I would like to keep only the **p-value**, **confidence interval**, and the **mean of x and mean of y** for each of these 48 tests and then build a table of the results.

Is there an elegant, quick way to do this beyond the top answer detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639424/get-a-single-value-out-of-any-statistics-tests-e-g-value-of-spearman-rho-out-o) , wherein I would go in for all 48 tests and grab all three desired outputs with something along the lines of `ttest$p.value`? Perhaps a loop?

Below is a sample of the coded input for one t-test, followed by the output delivered by R.

```
# t.test comparing means of Change_Unemp for 2005 government employment (ix)

lowgov6 <- met_res[met_res$Gov_Emp_2005 <= 93310, "Change_Unemp"]
highgov6 <- met_res[met_res$Gov_Emp_2005 > 93310, "Change_Unemp"]
t.test(lowgov6,highgov6,pool.sd=FALSE,na.rm=TRUE)  

Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  lowgov6 and highgov6
t = 1.5896, df = 78.978, p-value = 0.1159
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
-0.1813909  1.6198399
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
4.761224  4.042000
```

Comment: why did you do 48 by hand? What are they named? If the naming pattern is similar for all 48, then its easy enough

Comment: I did them prior to learning about loops and am still not sure how to execute one. I figured I'd find out if there was a way to do this rather than spending the time redoing my work for the t-tests in a loop.

Comment: See my question for automating `t.test`s: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55249057/t-test-create-lapply-function-for-multiple-grouping-levels/55249318#55249318

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Save all of your t-tests into a list:

```
tests <- list()
tests[[1]] <- t.test(lowgov6,highgov6,pool.sd=FALSE,na.rm=TRUE)
# repeat for all tests
# there are probably faster ways than doing all of that by hand

# extract your values using `sapply`
sapply(tests, function(x) {
     c(x$estimate[1],
       x$estimate[2],
       ci.lower = x$conf.int[1],
       ci.upper = x$conf.int[2],
       p.value = x$p.value)
})
```

The output is something like the following:

```
                 [,1]        [,2]
mean of x  0.12095949  0.03029474
mean of y -0.05337072  0.07226999
ci.lower  -0.11448679 -0.31771191
ci.upper   0.46314721  0.23376141
p.value    0.23534905  0.76434012
```

But will have 48 columns. You can `t()` the result if you'd like it transposed.

Comment: Hey @Thomas, thanks for sharing code. How can we get two confidence interval by amending your code? I found this code to do it individually for x or y variable. It'd be nice to do same with your code.  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86509/calculating-confidence-intervals-for-two-samples

Comment: @Rocky Please ask that as a new question here on the site, with a link to this question and answer and to that one from CrossValidated.