# t.test: create lapply function for multiple grouping levels

Tags: r, function, grouping, lapply

I'm trying to create an `lapply` function to run multiple `t.test`s for multiple levels of grouping. I came across this question: [Kruskal-Wallis test: create lapply function to subset data.frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50180546/kruskal-wallis-test-create-lapply-function-to-subset-data-frame) but they were only trying to group by one variable (`phase`). I would like to add another grouping level `color`, where my iv is `distance` and dv is `val` grouped by `color` then `phase`.

```
# create data
val<-runif(60, min = 0, max = 100)
distance<-floor(runif(60, min=1, max=3))
phase<-rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 20)
color<-rep(c("red", "blue","green","yellow","purple"), 12)

df<-data.frame(val, distance, phase, color)
```

Their answer for the grouping by `phase` was

```
lapply(split(df, df$phase), function(d) { kruskal.test(val ~ distance, data=d) })
```

However, it doesn't account for another level (`color`) for grouping. I might be approaching this wrong so I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply incorporate a `list()` inside `split` on needed column(s). However, with your sample this will create an error since some groups all share same *distance* values.

```
lapply(split(df, list(df$color, df$phase)), function(d) {
    kruskal.test(val ~ distance, data=d) 
})
```

> Error in kruskal.test.default(c(76.6759299905971, 3.11371604911983,
>   17.6471394719556,  :    all observations are in the same group

Consequently, consider wrapping in `tryCatch` to return `NA` or any other object for those problem groups:

```
lapply(split(df, list(df$color, df$phase)), function(d) {
    tryCatch({ kruskal.test(val ~ distance, data=d) },
             error = function(e) NA)
})
```

---

By the way, consider `by` (object-oriented wrapper to `tapply` and often overlooked member of apply family) instead of nesting `split` inside `lapply`:

```
by(df, df[c("color", "phase")], function(d) {
    tryCatch({ kruskal.test(val ~ distance, data=d) },
             error = function(e) NA)
})
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks! *`t.test` instead of `kruskal.test` :P